# Mysql Query Update Error Code

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I got this query but it doesn't update and gives me an error. I'm not really sure whats wrong with it, any help greatly appreciated.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE Link_Contact SET title='$title',desc='$desc' WHERE id='$id'") 
   or  die(mysql_error());
```

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `'desc='desc desc descdsfdsfds' WHERE id='1'' at line 1`

Answer (score 2):

`DESC` is an SQL [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html).  You would normally use it in an `ORDER BY` clause.

You can use SQL reserved words as column names if you delimit them.  In MySQL, the default delimiter is the back-tick, so for example you should put back-ticks around your column name `desc`:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE Link_Contact SET title='$title',`desc`='$desc' WHERE id='$id'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

`DESC` is a MySQL [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html), so if you are using `desc` as a column name you have to surround it with a backtick.